# Need regex that ignores date/sequence number, but matches the rest of the string

Tags: c++, date

I'm looking for a regex that ignores part of a larger string of text, specifically a date/sequence number. For example, the string looks like this:

E0618456458784NOS REGRESSION COMPANY  5454545455SAL         3-MAAAA2018/2/00192

I would like the regex to ignore the "2018/2/00192" but still match up the rest of the string. In the next file I use the regex for, the date/sequence number might be in a different location and the string may change, but the format will always be the same, meaning "2018/#/#####". I'm using C++ and I've gotten close with this regex (found on this site):

[^2018/2/00192]+

It ignores the date/sequence number, but it's also ignore the "0", "1", and "8" at the beginning of the line. I basically don't care about the "2018/2/00192" in the string because I know that's going to change. Everything else though, I want to match. Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: So which bits of the pattern are fixed? Just the "4-digits '/' 1-digit '/' 5-digits" shape? Some or all of the digits? That's clearly not a date btw, but you need to know what pattern you're trying to match before you can write a regex for it

Comment: The fixed part is the "2018/2/00192". It's basically the year, month, and a sequence number. The year will  always be 2018, the month can vary (1-12), and the sequence number will always be 5 digits. So, the pattern will be ####/#/#####, and it can appear anywhere in a line. I just need to be able to ignore that pattern, but still check everything before and after that, in the string. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you would do this in c++, but the sed equivalent of this would be

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]\{4\}\/[0-9]\/[0-9]\{5\}//" text
```

In programming languages like Perl, you could use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`